# Why does the number of links not matter in the transmission time of circuit switching?

Tags: networking

I am reading a book about networking, and it says that, in a circuit switching environment, the number of links and switches a signal has to go through before getting to destination does not affect the overall time it takes for all the signal to be received. On the other hand, in a packet switching scenario the number of links and switches does make a difference. I spent quite a bit of time trying to figure it out, but I can't seem to get it. Why is that?

Comment: Unless you can make a specific programming question out of this, I'm afraid it's off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To drastically over-simplify, effectively a circuit-switched environment has a direct line from the transmitter to the transmitted once a connection has been established; imagine an old-fashioned phone-call going through switchboards. Therefore the transmission time is the same regardless of hops (well, ignoring the physical time it takes the signal to move over the wire, which very small since it's moving at the speed of light).

In a packet-switched environment, there is no direct connection. A packet of data is sent from the transmitter to the first hop, which tries to calculate an open route to the destination. It then passes its data onto the next hop, which again has to calculate the next available hop, and so on. This takes time that linearly increases with the number of hops. Think sending a letter through the US postal system. It has to go from your house to a post office, then the post office to a local distribution center, then from the local distribution center to the national one, then from that to the recipient's local distribution center, then to the recipient's post office, then finally to their house.

The difference is that only one connection at a time per circuit can exist on a circuit-switched network; again, think phone line with someone using it to make a call. Whereas in a packet switched network many transmitters and receivers can be sending data at the same time; again, think many people sending/recieving letters.